# Changes in static files not visible

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using Intellij IDEA 13.1.3 for Spring + angular web app. Project is created using maven and app is running on embedded tomcat server (tomcat-maven-plugin).

I've created new source folder called src/main/javascript for storing angular code. The problem is that if I change any file inside that folder, changes are not visible in browser until the server is restarted. Problem disappers if I put files under webapp folder.

I assume I have to add something to pom? This is part of my pom:

```
 <build>
    <defaultGoal>clean install tomcat7:run</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
            <targetPath>resources/js</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>
```

Comment: how are you starting tomcat? with tomcat7:run ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript must be under `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: For obvious reasons, this triggered the low-quality filter. Please try and keeps answers of a decent standard. I'll give a minor edit to fix the obvious issues.

Comment: Javascript or HTML can be in custom folder, that is configurable and it works in Eclipse as expected. Also it works in Idea, but changes aren't automatically published. Something must be additionally configured in Intellij but I can't figure out what.